# I can't use my tellraw command with multiple {text:"_"} segments

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to know what's wrong with this command:

```
/tellraw @p {text:"You have joined ",color:white,extra:[{text:"Breakfast Baker!",color:green,bold:true,{text:"Breakfast Baker is a 5-player game, where you have to bake breakfast for a judge, ",color:white,bold:false,{text:"Villager Ramsay, ",color:orange,{text:"and if you have the best breakfast, you ",color:white,bold:false,{text:"WIN!",color:gold,bold:true}}}}}]}
```

It says

```
invalid json: expected name at line 1 column 92
```

I don't know what's wrong... it's supposed to say

> "You have joined Breakfast Baker! Breakfast Baker is a 5-player game, where you have to bake breakfast for a judge, Villager Ramsay, and if you have the best breakfast, you WIN!"

With different colors, bold and other flair. Can anyone help?

Comment: So...what's at column 92?

Comment: @Frank How do I find column 92? Sorry if it's a dumb question...

Comment: That generally means character 92, when looking at code-type stuff.  For this command, that's right after the `color:green`, but.  It says it's looking for a name.  I don't work with Minecraft, though, so I have no idea how valid that is.

Comment: Well, nothing's really after color:green, so no idea... P.S how do you make the color:green in a gray square?

Comment: Well, that's at the beginning of your command, and you have `bold:true` right after.  Maybe it's looking for a name property?

Comment: I'm so sorry but I have no idea what a name property is...

Comment: Something like `name:Baker`, maybe?  Worth a shot, anyways.  I'd recommend stripping the command down to a single color, and seeing if that works.  Build on it piece by piece, and test it every step of the way.

Comment: Try using this [JSON Creator.](https://www.minecraftjson.com/) I had a play around in it and it seems to be fairly straightforward. Once you have built the command, compare it with your original attempt and see where the issue was.

Comment: Post the solution as an answer (self-solved problems are often highly regarded) so anyone else that has the same issue can find the solution as well :)

Comment: I started looking into it and I found that it was within the 
_{text:"Breakfast Baker is a 5-player game, where you have to bake breakfast for a judge, " -_
Line of Code, but glad you found you're answer :)

Answer (score 4):

I found this [JSON Creator](https://www.minecraftjson.com/) for Minecraft commands, and after having a bit of a play with it, the issue is being caused by the use of the command

```
extra:[...
```

The issue is that this section isn't terminated correctly, causing it to throw the error.

Instead, this command can be built in muliptle `{text:...}` sections, like so:

```
/tellraw @p ["",{"text":"You have joined ","color":"white"},{"text":"Breakfast Baker! ","color":"green","bold":true},{"text":"Breakfast Baker is a 5-player game, where you have to bake breakfast for a judge, ","color":"white","bold":false},{"text":"Villager Ramsay, ","color":"yellow"},{"text":"and if you have the best breakfast, you ","color":"white"},{"text":"WIN!","color":"gold","bold":true}]
```

Resulting in:

[image: Minecraft /tellraw]

Comment: `extra` was terminated okay-ish. It was the compound tags within extra that weren't closed at the correct position.

Answer (score 2):

> color:green,bold:true, **{** text:"Breakfast Baker

You are opening an object with a curly bracket but did not give it a name before it. That issue is repeated at other points in the command.

If you were intending to use it as another record within the `extra` list, then you need to close the previous record completely first (by applying a closing curly bracket):

> color:green,bold:true **}** , { text:"Breakfast Baker

Fixed command, applying needed closing curly brackets and removing extra closing brackets at the end:

```
/tellraw @p {text:"You have joined ",color:white,extra:[{text:"Breakfast Baker!",color:green,bold:true},{text:"Breakfast Baker is a 5-player game, where you have to bake breakfast for a judge, ",color:white,bold:false},{text:"Villager Ramsay, ",color:orange},{text:"and if you have the best breakfast, you ",color:white,bold:false},{text:"WIN!",color:gold,bold:true}]}
```

For 1.9's strict JSON requirement:

```
tellraw @p {"text":"You have joined ","color":"white","extra":[{"text":"Breakfast Baker!","color":"green","bold":true},{"text":"Breakfast Baker is a 5-player game, where you have to bake breakfast for a judge, ","color":"white","bold":false},{"text":"Villager Ramsay, ","color":"orange"},{"text":"and if you have the best breakfast, you ","color":"white","bold":false},{"text":"WIN!","color":"gold","bold":true}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it (:
it's

```
/tellraw @p ["",{"text":"You have joined "},{"text":"Breakfast Baker","color":"green","bold":true},{"text":", a game where you bake breakfast for a judge, ","color":"none","bold":false},{"text":"Villager Ramsay, ","color":"red"},{"text":"and whoever has the best breakfast ","color":"none"},{"text":"WINS!","color":"gold","bold":true}]
```

for anyone who is coming on the page to know what's wrong. What's wrong was I forgot to put the } after a text segment so it looked like this: `{text:"the text"` and no `},` so I just fixed it.